# Does MonoDevelop support custom targets in project (csproj) files?

Tags: .net, msbuild, monodevelop

For example adding this to a csproj

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      <Exec Command="foo.exe arg1 arg2"  />
</Target>
```

For me it seems to be ignoring them

Comment: I don't think MonoDevelop will do that; but [xbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build) will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn it on in the options screen

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 0):

MD supports MSBuild projects by mapping them into its old internal build engine, which can't support arbitrary MSBuild constructs like this.

There is experimental support to use MSBuild/xbuild as the build engine, and you can enable this in MD Preferences.